# Not sure why it says "column ambiguously defined"

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting "column ambiguously defined."

```
WITH CountData as (
  SELECT BOARD_RATE_T1,
         BOARD_RATE_T3,
         RENTAL_START_DATE,
         RENTAL_END_DATE,
         (BOARD_RATE_T3 - BOARD_RATE_T1) AS Countt
  FROM PPSS.PA_OA_RATE_JUST
),
GroupCount AS
(
  SELECT BOARD_RATE_T1,
         BOARD_RATE_T3,
         Countt,
         CASE
             WHEN Countt < 500 THEN 'Under 500'
             WHEN Countt BETWEEN 500 AND 5000 THEN '500 - 5000'
             WHEN Countt BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000 THEN '5000 - 10000'
             WHEN Countt > 10000 THEN 'Over 10000'
             ELSE 'Invalid Count'
         END AS Countt
  FROM CountData
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountGrpCount,
      Countt Groups
FROM GroupCount;
```

Comment: Because you have defined `COUNTT` twice in `GroupCount`.  That is just a guess.

Comment: Almost what Gordon says - except that in the `SELECT` list of `GROUPCOUNT` you only defined `COUNTT` once (as the result of a `CASE` expression), and you also included the column `COUNTT` - with the same name - from the earlier CTE.

Comment: Note also that `BETWEEN` means non-strict inequalities at both ends. With the `CASE` expression as written, a value of exactly 5000 will fall in the 500-5000 range (simply because the conditions in `CASE` are evaluated in the order they are written), but keep this in mind for other uses of `BETWEEN`. In most cases, if you have more than one `BETWEEN` condition in a compound condition put together with `AND` or `OR` operators, something is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: I need the records in the table to be organized by the case logic defined.

Comment: What mathguy is saying: '500 - 5000' and '5000 - 10000' both include the value 5000. So what result do you want for the value 5000? So far '500 - 5000' wins - just because it comes first in the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last query is throwing the error because you're referencing `Countt` and it's defined twice in `GroupCount`. Oracle doesn't know which one you mean.

Once you get past the ambiguous column error you'll have trouble with the final query. Oracle is strict about requiring a `GROUP BY` for every non-aggregate value in an aggregate query, unlike say MySQL. There are exceptions, like constants and functions like `SYSDATE`, but that's out of scope for this question.

If you're trying to get counts by "Under 500", "500 - 5000", etc. then here are a couple things I noticed about the query:

1. You don't need the `BOARD_RATE_T1`, `BOARD_RATE_T2`, `RENTAL_START_DATE` and `RENTAL_END_DATE` columns.
2. The Rate Difference category `CASE` statement can be shortened and made slightly less error-prone by changing the logic a bit.
3. The only way you'll hit the `ELSE` condition in the `CASE` statement is if `BOARD_RATE_T1` and/or `BOARD_RATE_T3` are null. If they're both required (`NOT NULL`) values you can leave out the `ELSE`.

This query will give the counts. My apologies if you do need the other values and were hacking them out to make the question shorter :)

```
WITH CountData AS (
  SELECT BOARD_RATE_T3 - BOARD_RATE_T1 AS RateDiff
  FROM PPSS.PA_OA_RATE_JUST
),
GroupCount AS (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN RateDiff < 500 THEN 'Under 500'
      WHEN RateDiff < 5000 THEN '500 - 5000'
      WHEN RateDiff < 10000 THEN '5000 - 10000'
      ELSE 'Invalid Count'
    END AS RateDiffCategory
  FROM CountData
)
SELECT
  RateDiffCategory,
  COUNT(*)
FROM GroupCount
GROUP BY
  RateDiffCategory
ORDER BY
  RateDiffCategory
```